# Create a Profile object for existing Devise Users on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I just created a Profile model for attributes such as name, website, bio for my Devise users. Everything works great, except on Heroku, I have 100+ users already, so it's fairly tedious to 1. create a new Profile, 2. assign it to the existing user 3. save, all in the console.

I am not familiar with what you can do in the Heroku console and if this is even possible -- but can I mass create 100+ new Profiles for each existing User (that does not already have a Profile).

Right now, any view that has Profile info (ie user.profile.name) is giving me an error -- I would rather create a blank profile than force Users to create a new one in the interface.

Rails 3.2.12

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :build_profile
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :role, :profile_attributes
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :bio, :name, :website, :user_id

belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file add_profile_to_users.rake under lib/tasks:

```
task :add_profile_to_users => :environment do
    User.all.each do |u| #where no profile
        puts "Updating user id #{u.id}..."
            if u.profile.nil?
               u.build_profile
           else
                puts "skip"
            end
        puts "...#{u.name} has been updated!" if u.save
    end
end
```

which I ran from the console with: rake add_profile_to_users

This worked and should work on heroku as well.

Answer (score 1):

To have rails console on heroku:

```
heroku run rails console
```

Another solution could be to create a migration CreateProfileForUsers and migrate it on your prod as you deploy:

```
def up
  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.profile.nil?
       user.build_profile
    end
  end
end

def down
end
```

**EDIT**

I just learnt that it is a bad practice to use migrations for this! It is better to create a rake task that builds your profile and run it as soon as you deploy.

Comment: You may need to use user.save depending on how your build_profile is created.

Comment: I did include user.save - didn't realize migrations could be used for this, but makes so much sense. Thank you!!

Comment: thanks! I did end up writing a rake task. i will add it in a separate answer.